# how to import data into django

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I am trying to use Django to write a web application. I have seen several Django tutorials. Somehow they all demonstrate how to manually type in information into the database. Maybe I am missing something. But is there anyway, the information shows in a from is read from a table, say a matlab mat file. I know how to do it in python as follows.

```
from scipy import io as sio
from numpy import random

import numpy
mat = sio.loadmat('plm.mat')   #type(mat1)  dictionary
mat1 = mat['plm']   #type(mat1)
random.shuffle(mat1)
```

mat is a matrix only containing integers. My question is, when rendering a form, how to let it read the numbers in mat1?

Thank you!

Comment: add form in the template to upload the mat file. Inside the views get the file and use your python code to process through it and send the result  back to the template

Comment: Hi thanks! I upload the form in model.py and now it works! Just for future preferences, do we have a particular reason to upload the mat file in html template?

Comment: yes, since the processing of the mat file has to be done by python, that's why we have to send it to the server side for processing.

Comment: hi how can we "add form in the  html template to upload the mat file"? at the moment I am doing it in a constant class in models.py and import the class in views.py.

Comment: another questions is, this seems can be much easier done than usually suggested. We do not even need to bother with a database. What is the reason that people want to build a database for this type of thing?

Comment: For learning how to process forms in django follow this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Python for processing your matlab file, and you want a web interface for that, you will have to use Django backend to process your file from the server side. Might not be necessary you use a database. Can work without it also.